# Adobe CQ5.6 timing chart url for performance monitoring not shown

Tags: performance

I have read in developer guide (Adobe CQ 5.6) that to monitior the performance of the page created, you should open the page in author instance and right-click to see the HTML source. There at the end you will see URL 'Timing chart URL'.
But I am not able to see this URL. Any body have idea what can be wrong on my end? I am using Adobe CQ 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Coding in CQ:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJaXmMtZSCU

Answer for your query: Refer correct documents, Please visit http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/performance.html & also share the link where you read the following?

Comment: I read it in 'Adobe CQ 5.6 Developer Student Exercise Workbook'. Page 266 and Exercise 12.4
This is not on web page. It is PDF file.

Comment: You need to comment few lines in  /libs/foundation/components/timing/timing.jsp and then need to include this component on page, Follow this:
http://www.wemblog.com/2014/05/how-to-find-component-load-time-on-page.html

Comment: In wemblog it is written 'Make sure that timing.jsp is included in your global template using'.
By 'global template' you mean global.jsp, if yes then this thing is making issue for me i.e. at the end of global.jsp I have added this
'<cq:include path="timing" resourceType="foundation/components/timing"/>' right next to '<cq:defineObjects />'.
But unfortunately I am getting exception when I load my page in browser i.e. 'Cannot serve request to /cf in /libs/foundation/components/timing/timing.jsp' and in stacktrace I see 'org.apache.sling.api.SlingException'